# RecyclerView makes single Items go left instead of them staying on the right

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I just started an new app (an easy chat app) on Android and Im kind of stuck in the recyclerView. I am switching between 2 XML files to display a message either on the left or on the right of the screen. The messages on the left work fine, but the messages which should be displayed on the right jump to the left when debugging the app. In the original XML they are connected to the right with constraints.

Here is the code of the xml file of the message on the right:

```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:text="Hi, sub?" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the code from the adapter
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

```
private final Context mContext;
private final static int showLeft = 1;
private final static int showRight = 0;

public ChatAdapter(@NonNull Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public NumberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int layoutId;

    switch(viewType){
        case showLeft:
            layoutId = R.layout.message_received;
            Log.d("Inflation: ", "left");
            break;

        case showRight:
            layoutId = R.layout.message_sent;
            Log.d("Inflation: ", "right");
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type, value of " + viewType);
    }

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
    view.setFocusable(true);
    return new NumberViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NumberViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.message.setText(DataHandling.ChatMessages.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return DataHandling.ChatMessages.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(DataHandling.MessageState.get(position) == 1){
        return showRight;                               //If the message was received
    }else{
        return showLeft;
    }
}

public class NumberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView message;
    public NumberViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);
    }
}
```

How can I make them stick to the right side of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below, I basically replaced the Constraint Layout with Relative Layout and given layout_alignParentRight to true. this should work.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        tools:text="Hi, sub?" />
</RelativeLayout>
```